# Scheduled task fires even when hard drives are not idle in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks

TL;DR;:

1. Can I increase the verification time for idle time in Windows 8?
2. Is streaming a movie from computer A with Computer B enough to keep computer A out of the idle state?

### The case

Given [the description from Microsoft regarding when an Task sees the system as being idle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx), I was sure that an active hard drive was enough to keep the system out of the `idle` state.

> The computer is considered idle if all the processors and all the
>   disks were idle for more than 90% of the last detection interval.

I tested this by sharing my `D:` drive, storing a movie on it, and the started streaming this movie from an another computer.

I am afraid that since I am using Windows 10, I am running into this issue.

> When the user is away, the verification time is shortened to 30 second
>   intervals.

I would think that as I am streaming the movie, I am buffering enough data to make the intervals between fetching data less frequent than 30 seconds.

Comment: Accessing a file on a hdd isn't going to use much CPU at all - DMA makes sure of this, which makes the windows definition of 'idle' kind of unusable. Not sure how to fix it though :/